# Вызов метода, прекращение и повторный запуск InvokeRepeating Unity 5

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть в скрипте C# несколько методов, которые вызываются по очереди через InvokeRepeating.(собака бегает, собака лает) Надо чтобы при вызове одного из этих методов(собака спит) , InvokeRepeating прекращалось и вызывалась в следующий раз уже вручную(когда собаку разбудить). Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InvokeRepeating` можно прервать за счет [CancelInvoke](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.CancelInvoke.html)

Если вызвать `CancelInvoke()` без параметров, то будут отменены все вызовы `Invoke` в данном скрипте.

Чтоб отменить конкретный `Invoke` - нужно передать имя того метода, который следует прервать.

Например, запуск был так:

```
InvokeRepeating("RespawnCreatures", 0, 3);
```

а отменить его можно так:

```
CancelInvoke("RespawnCreatures");
```

Comment: Благодарю, я пользуюсь уже этим методом, проблема то в том как запустить это снова. Вот мой код. Running не запускается снова, а нужно чтобы запускался при прикосновении к экрану
 
`void Update()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) { ohoho1++; }
        {

void son()
    {
        dir = new Vector3(0, 0, -1);
        myTransform.Translate(dir * 0);
        CancelInvoke();
        if(ohoho1 > 0)
        {
            InvokeRepeating("Running", 1, 2);
            ohoho1 = 0;
        }`

Comment: Может дело в том на что я вешаю этот скрипт? Если скрипт висит на собаке, то и клики он считает тоже только по собаке? Или он считает клик по всему?

Comment: @Dmitrii Я без понятия. Я не экстрасенс. Я не знаю что у вас там во всей игре за логика, что где расположено, что где написано, что чем управляет и что вообще планируется..........Может при нажатии у вас не срабатывает одно из условий, которое на рабочесть вы можете проверить банально написав `Debug.Log("Im here");`, а можно воспользоваться дебагом, как это все делают.....А может ошибка вываливается в это время и поэтому не отрабатывает..........вручную вызвать можно просто `Running()` ......